# All content of file get duplicated while modifying a specific entry

Tags: c, file, structure

This code read/write data to/from binary file. Here `modify()` will take input from user, search for it in the file. If found, will prompt user to give new entry and the older entry would be replaced.

The question is, in `modify()` after `fwrite()` if I `break` the `while` loop then everything would be fine but, if I don't then the entry would still be modified but along with that the content of the file would be duplicated, why so ?

As in the beginning there are no duplicate entries in the file. **So what I expect is,** that even if I don't use `break` the loop should go on and finally terminate when whole file has been read. Here, the `if(strcmp(e.name,user)==0)` would only be true for one entry therefore the control should enter only once in this `if` block. Then how the entries are getting duplicated ?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    void add(FILE *);
    void list(FILE *);
    void modify(FILE *);

    struct emp
    {
        char name[20];
        int id;
        float sal;
    }e;

    void add(FILE *f)
    {
        char *p=NULL;

        printf("\nEnter name id sal\n");
        scanf(" %s %d %f", e.name,&e.id,&e.sal);

        fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
        if((fwrite(&e,sizeof(struct emp),1,f))==1)
        {
            printf("\nAdded Successfully\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nError wrting to file in ADD func\n");
        }
    }

    void list(FILE *f)
    {
        rewind(f);
        while(fread(&e,sizeof(struct emp),1,f)>0)
        {
            printf("\nRead %s %d %f\n",e.name,e.id,e.sal);
        }
    }

    void modify(FILE *f)
    {
        char user[20];
        char *p=NULL;

        printf("\nEnter name to modify\n");
        scanf(" %s", user);

        rewind(f);

        while(fread(&e,sizeof(struct emp),1,f)==1)
        {
            //printf("\n        --------------- %s %d %f\n",e.name,e.id,e.sal);
            if(strcmp(e.name,user)==0)
            {
                //fseek(f,-sizeof(struct emp),SEEK_CUR);
                printf("\nEnter new name id salary\n");
                scanf(" %s %d %f", e.name,&e.id,&e.sal);

                fseek(f,-sizeof(struct emp),SEEK_CUR);
                if(fwrite(&e,sizeof(struct emp),1,f)==1)
                {
                    printf("\nModified successfull!!\n");
                    //break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nError while modifying\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nstring not matched\n\n");
            }
        }

    }

    int main()
    {
        char val='T';
        FILE *fp=NULL;

        if((fp=fopen("database.dat","rb+"))==NULL)
        {
            if((fp=fopen("database.dat","wb+"))==NULL)
            {
                printf("\nError opening file in wb+ mode\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        do
        {
            printf("\nEnter a to add, l to list, d to delete, m to modify and e to exit\n");
            scanf(" %c", &val);

            switch(val)
            {
                case 'a':
                        add(fp);
                        break;
                case 'l':
                        list(fp);
                        break;
                case 'm':
                        modify(fp);
                        break;
                case 'd':
    //                    del(fp);
                        break;
                case 'e':
                        fclose(fp);
                        exit(0);
                        break;
                default:
                        printf("\nInvalid Input\n");
                        break;
            }

        }
        while(1);

    }
```

Comment: Once you invoked undefined behaviour, anything can happen. `fflush(stdin)` does invoke undefined behaviour. Before asking here remove all known cases of undefined behaviour. As you seem not to really know what undefined behaviour implies, learn about it!

Comment: @Olaf All occurences of ````fflush(stdin)```` removed. Please check it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a problem between `fread()` and `fwrite()`.
After you use fwrite() to modify the `emp`, you continue the `while` loop without using `fseek()`.
In fact, before, you used fseek() to go back and it was OK.
Now you have to place another fseek() which doesn't move, like this:

```
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

Now you can remove the break and your `Modify()` function would seems like this:

```
void modify(FILE *f)
{
    char user[20];
    printf("\nEnter name to modify\n");
    scanf("%s",user);
    fflush(stdin);
    rewind(f);

    while(fread(&e,sizeof(struct emp),1,f)==1)
    {
        if(strcmp(e.name,user)==0)
        {
            printf("\nEnter new name id salary\n");
            scanf("%s %d %f",e.name,&e.id,&e.sal);
            fflush(stdin);

            fseek(f,-sizeof(struct emp),SEEK_CUR);
            if(fwrite(&e,sizeof(struct emp),1,f)==1)
            {
                printf("\nModified successfull!!\n");
                //break; //This can be removed

                fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR); //Place this here
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nError while modifying\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\nstring not matched\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works but, why do we need to do this ````fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR);```` because after writing the ````fwrite```` makes the file pointer point to next entry on it's own ? So the loop should continue from next entry on it's own ?

Comment: See [Standard 7.21.5.3p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7): "... output/input shall not be directly followed by input/output without an intervening call to the fflush function ..."

Comment: @pmg "output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function `(fseek, fsetpos, or rewind)` " So as per this if we use `fflush()` then it would be done over `stdout`?

Comment: if you use `fflush()` you must use it for the `FILE *` you are using for freads and fwrites. If that file is a input file, or a input/output file for which the last operation was input, `fflush()` causes Undefined Behaviour (except, as far as I know, in [Microsoft Windows library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx))